# How can I join two datasets using a key in OpenRefine, with the secondary table having more than one value?

Tags: openrefine

I have a dataset X like this:

```
Code | Name
------------
123  | AAA
456  | BBB
```

And the other Y like this:

```
Code | Level
------------
123  | A
123  | B
456  | B
456  | C
```

I want to join them using OpenRefine to something like this:

```
Code | Name | Level A | Level B | Level C
------------------------------------------
123  | AAA  |  value  |  value  |   -
456  | BBB  |    -    |  value  | value
```

When I try to add a column using cell.cross() from '*X.Code*' it only gets the value from the first appearance of '*X.Code*' in '*Y*'.

```
cell.cross("Y", "Code")[0].cells["Rede"].value[0]
```

How can I get to this desired output, using GREL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Columnize by key/value your project Y to have one column by Level  like the example below. Use `Transpose -> Columnize by key/value`

```
Code | Level A | Level B | Level C
------------------------------------------
123  | value  |  value  |   -
456  |   -    |  value  | value
```

Then you can use the cell.cross function for each column. For example: `cell.cross("Y", "Code")[0].cells["Level A"].value[0]` to import the data into the Project X

Comment: Thanks @magdmartin, it worked! Just for completion, I had to remove all non-duplicate columns for this procedure to work, as it may not always be desired.

Comment: Happy to see it works. Please accept the answer so the community knows this is answered.